# A lens for getting or setting a record field determined by a runtime argument

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I have these types (and more):

```
data Player = PlayerOne | PlayerTwo deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Enum, Bounded)

data Point = Love | Fifteen | Thirty deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Enum, Bounded)

data PointsData =
  PointsData { pointsToPlayerOne :: Point, pointsToPlayerTwo :: Point }
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
```

I'm doing the [Tennis kata](http://codingdojo.org/kata/Tennis), and as part of the implementation, I'd like to use some functions that enable me to get or set the points for an arbitrary player, only known at runtime.

Formally, I need functions like these:

```
pointFor :: PointsData -> Player -> Point
pointFor pd PlayerOne = pointsToPlayerOne pd
pointFor pd PlayerTwo = pointsToPlayerTwo pd

pointTo :: PointsData -> Player -> Point -> PointsData
pointTo pd PlayerOne p = pd { pointsToPlayerOne = p }
pointTo pd PlayerTwo p = pd { pointsToPlayerTwo = p }
```

As demonstrated, my problem isn't that I can't implement these functions.

They do, however, look *lens-like* to me, so I wonder if I could get that functionality via the `lens` library?

Most of the lens tutorials show how to get or set a particular, named part of a bigger data structure. This doesn't quite seem to fit what I'm trying to do here; rather, I'm trying to get or set a sub-part determined at runtime.

Comment: Would a function `pointsToPlayer :: Player -> Lens' PointsData Points` be enough? (Can't test it right now, but I'm quite sure a direct implementation of that would work right away.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [answer from *Fyodor Soikin*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56468368/2751851) and comment from *duplode*, I ended up using `makeLenses` from *lens* and writing a function that returns the appropriate lens:

```
data PointsData =
  PointsData { _pointsToPlayerOne :: Point, _pointsToPlayerTwo :: Point }
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
makeLenses ''PointsData

playerPoint :: Player -> Lens' PointsData Point
playerPoint PlayerOne = pointsToPlayerOne
playerPoint PlayerTwo = pointsToPlayerTwo
```

It can be used like this fragment of a bigger function:

```
score :: Score -> Player -> Score
-- ..
score (Points pd) winner = Points $ pd & playerPoint winner %~ succ
-- ..
```

Answer (score 6):

An excursion into somewhat abstract typeclasses. Your `PointsData` has a special relationship with the `Player` type. It's a bit like a `Map Player Point`, with the particularity that for *every* possible value of `Player`, there's *always* a corresponding `Point`. In a way, `PointsData` is like a "reified function" `Player -> Point`.

If we make `PointsData` polymorphic on the type of `Points`, it would fit with the [`Representable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html) typeclass. We would say that `PointsData` is "represented" by `Player`.

`Representable` is often useful as an interface to tabular data, like in the [grids](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/grids-0.5.0.1/docs/Data-Grid.html) package.

---

So one possible solution would be to turn `PointsData` into an actual `Map`, but hide the implementation behind a smart constructor that took a `Player -> Point` function to initialize it for all possible keys (it would correspond to the [`tabulate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html) method of `Representable`).

The user should not be able to delete keys from the map. But we could piggyback on the [`Ixed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#t:Ixed) instance of `Map` to provide traversals.

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.Map.Strict -- from "containers"

newtype PointsData = PointsData { getPoints :: Map Player Point } 

init :: (Player -> Point) -> PointsData
init f = PointsData (Data.Map.Strict.fromList ((\p -> (p, f p)) <$> [minBound..maxBound]))


playerPoints :: Player -> Lens' PointsData Point
playerPoints pl = Control.Lens.singular (iso getPoints PointsData . ix pl)
```

Comment: I find that the concept of thinking about `PointsData` as a map aligns closely with my original thoughts, and I had hoped there'd be something more closely related to such a concept. Since, however, I'm trying to explore ways to model problem domains, I don't consider it appropriate to make `PointsData` polymorphic.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a function that produces a `Lens` given a `Player`, like this:

```
playerPoints :: Player -> Lens' PointsData Point
playerPoints PlayerOne = field @"pointsToPlayerOne"
playerPoints PlayerTwo = field @"pointsToPlayerTwo"
```

(this is using [`field` from `generic-lens`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.24/generic-lens-1.1.0.0/Data-Generics-Product-Fields.html#v:field))

Usage would be like this:

```
pts :: PointsData

pl1 = pts ^. playerPoints PlayerOne
pl2 = pts ^. playerPoints PlayerTwo

newPts = pts & playerPoints PlayerOne .~ 42
```

---

P.S. Or were you looking for picking a field of `PointsData` by matching field name to `Player` constructor name? That is also possible via `Generic`, but doesn't seem worth the trouble.

Comment: Footnote: this works just as well with lenses from *lens* -- the only difference is how the two lenses happen to be defined.