# Is there a string-based lens for runtime field access?

Tags: haskell, jsonpath, haskell-lens

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468091/a-lens-for-getting-or-setting-a-record-field-determined-by-a-runtime-argument), but even more runtime-ey.

Is there a way to automatically generate lenses, or any other mechanism, for accessing fields by name at runtime?

I'm looking for something similar to [`field` from `generic-lens`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.24/generic-lens-1.1.0.0/Data-Generics-Product-Fields.html#v:field), except taking the field name as a runtime argument instead of a type-leve parameter (and returning a `Maybe`).

I'm comfortable enough writing this myself, but I think it probably already exists.

### Example

```hs
data Foo = Foo { bar :: Bar }
data Bar = ...
```

Deriving `Generic`, you can use `generic-lens` to get the handy `field @"bar"` lens - but is there any way to automatically generate/derive a `fieldAtRuntime "bar"` which behaves the same (or a similar) way?

### Motivation

I want to navigate some custom data structures using JSON paths. It doesn't really matter to me that the JSON might not match up exactly with the record fields, but I do want to not have to serialize, traverse, and de-serialize.

Comment: I actually doubt that this exists, because **a)** it seems pretty un-idiomatic **b)** as you said it can be done, and maybe _should_ be done, on a (by nature dynamic) Aeson type, rather than a typed Haskell ADT.

Comment: It's only my motivation that brings in the Aeson consideration. Without it, this question is more "has someone already written some TH to derive an `Indexable String` instance for records which does the right thing?".

Comment: Yes, but unless you're doing something JSON-ish, I don't see a good reason why you'd want such an instance. Source code details such as field names aren't really supposed to exist at runtime (the default behaviour of `Show`/`Read` notwithstanding, but those are mostly debugging helpers).